# Tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.tracking' has no attribute 'TrackableSaver' Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I got this error after installing Tensorflow.js. Previously this program was working. Could it be a problem with the versions? I'm really curious as to what's causing it.
Thanks in advance.

```
File ~\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Bitirme Proje\neural_network(sinir_ağları).py:61
    model = build_model()

  File ~\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Bitirme Proje\neural_network(sinir_ağları).py:29 in build_model
    model = keras.Sequential([

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py:205 in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:3331 in saver_with_op_caching
    return tf.__internal__.tracking.TrackableSaver(

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.tracking' has no attribute 'TrackableSaver'
```

I was planning to convert my model with Tensorflow.js and run it over the web. But when I installed Tensorflow.js I got this error in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `keras` with `pip install 'keras>=2.9.0'` for [keras-team/keras@af70910](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/af70910ffc1d8a3591bfea76728029e100e92a7b).

> ```
> -    self._trackable_saver = saver_with_op_caching(self)
> +    self._checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(root=weakref.ref(self))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create another environment on Jupyter and re-install all the libraries from scratch since it seemed all the libraries started having issues, not just TensorFlow. It is now working with no errors.